# Importing a package with an interface and a class

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi, eclipse-neon

I am trying to create a Java package to interface with Excel, so I am using the org.apache.poi libraries. I've found the documentation on the [POI site](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook) that shows the following:

**Reading and Rewriting Workbooks**

```
(truncated)
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

When I attempt to create a Workbook object, I get errors that it doesn't know the type. The documentation above doesn't show the import statements, but if I'm reading [these POI docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) correctly, I should be able to import `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`, (and it's distinctly possible that I'm wrong because I'm very new to Java) but trying all of the following import statements all result in errors for the Workbook type.

```
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
```

I should note that I'm using Eclipse Neon for this, and the editor is not complaining that it can't find the packages, so I'm not sure where the issue lies.

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
```

The actual error I'm getting in the editor is that `"Workbook cannot be resolved to a type"`, and the same error for WorkbookFactory.

So the TL;DR is that the POI docs show that Workbook is an Interface in `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` and that WorkbookFactory is a class in the same usermodel package, but I can't figure out how to import/use them correctly.

EDIT: 
The build time error I receive is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Workbook cannot be resolved to a type
    WorkbookFactory cannot be resolved
    at spreadsheet.conversion.ConvertXLSXtoCSV.main(ConvertXLSXtoCSV.java:31)
```

The message I posted before was the editor popup... I was able to take a screenshot:

[image]

EDIT: Posting the full code, because, why not. (The multiple import statements
were just trying things out, mostly in desperation.)

```
package spreadsheet.conversion; 
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class ConvertXLSXtoCSV {

    private static String inputfilename = "";
    private static String outputfilename = "";
    private static int debug = 0;


    private static void test(String arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new Exception("Requires 1 parameter. Usage: ConvertXLSXtoCSV <filename>");
        }
        inputfilename = args[0];

        if(debug==1) {
            test(inputfilename);
        }
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(inputfilename);

        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);


    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full error and whether you are getting it at compile or runtime? It would be best also if you write a small [MCVE] of this.

Comment: I guess the actual message is "Workbook cannot be resolved to a type". Always post the exact error message (copy and paste it). Have you added the required libraries (poi and its dependencies) in the build path of your eclipse project?

Comment: Refer https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html, I guess there could be a conflict between `HSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook`

Comment: If you have the POI jar in your classpath, you can let Eclipse add the imports for you so that Eclipse will add the specific imports instead of the ones with asteriscs, which can contain anbiguous import resolutions. Use the **Reorganize Imports** option in the source code or type `Ctrl + space` near each class so Eclipse can add its import and be sure it is the correct one.

Comment: i got recomended XSSFWorkbook over Workbook that it can handle large file , so if you can use XSSFWorkbook , then use  `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
`  here is nice tutorial , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_workbooks.htm

Comment: The message that I get during build is `WorkbookFactory cannot be resolved at...(file/linenum)`. The message I posted is the popup that the editor is saying it can't find the definitions, telling me that either the POI libraries are not correctly installed, or I'm not accessing them correctly. (Updated the post with this info.)

Comment: Again, have you added the poi jar and its dependencies to the build path of your eclipse project?

Comment: Sorry forgot to address that, yes I added them to the build path, and there are no complaints from the editor (like the one I got before adding to the buildpath) that Eclipse can't resolve the import.

Comment: This is basically an Eclipse project configuration issue, doesn't have anything to do with imports or really Java as such. Your project needs to include the relevant dependencies and it appears that it doesn't.

Comment: If I imported all of the jar files in the POI package (which I have), and Eclipse isn't complaining that it can't find the imports I listed, what other configuration is there?

Comment: Eclipse seems to be complaining, given that popup. I'd recommend you use maven and pom files for your project build and dependencies - this can be imported into any IDE and also works straight from the command line. That way you're not dependent on the IDE for that stuff (and, as importantly, can switch to a saner IDE if you want).

Comment: Ok. I assumed that it wasn't eclipse because the actual import statements themselves didn't have any warnings/errors... I'll check out using Maven, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: They might have, if you'd used explicit, non-wildcard imports (which is the typical practice). One thing that might be confusing there - in Java, import statements don't actually do anything - they're pure syntax so you don't have to type fully qualified type names everywhere in your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As unhelpful to others as this may be, it's the solution I've come up with so I'm posting it as an answer. Many thanks for the comments about this, but I've always hated Eclipse, and decided to go with NetBeans IDE instead. It was extremely trivial to right click on Libraries, Add JAR/Folder, and select the POI jar files, and it (and the integrated Maven install) took care of the details and it worked perfectly right off the bat and resolved all library dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this due to jar file corrupted ( most probably during download for the first time). Here what you can do.

You can delete all poi folder in maven repository `.m2/repository/org/apache/poi`  then you can update maven by Right Click on the project > Maven > Update Project. Eclipse will automatically download the dependencies and auto rebuild the workspace.

im facing the same thing like yours and manage to get it clean.